# p1 script not running with schedule job

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, pnp-powershell, powershell-script

I have SP2010 in WIN2008R2, i have script(datemodifier.ps1) to update the diff of 2 dates in SP list daily, When I run the script manually its updating the list, but when i schedule it with a task on task scheduler its not working.

Steps I performed:

Step-1

**General**: **Runs whether user logs in or not**
**Triggers**: **Daily**
**Action**: **Start a programm**, **Programm/Script**: **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe**, **Add arguments(optional)**: **-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Filepath**

Not worked.

Step2:

Tried **Programm/Script**: **PowerShell.exe**,  **Add arguments(optional)**: **filepath.ps1** 
not working

I need a solution ASAP. Thankful in advance.

Comment: More preferred way is to use SharePoint timer Job or Site workflow to achieve your requirement. PS script is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the SharePoint PowerShell modules in your script? 
If not, try adding the following to the start of your script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

When you start the SharePoint Management shell this is automatically loaded. This could explain the different behaviours.